# syntax error: operand expected [error token is "/ "]

Tags: bash, shell, nagios

`DSKUSDPERCENT=$(($DISKUSD * 100 / $limit))` throughs error like

> syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ ") where
> limit=$OPTARG defined in Process command line options

here I am not able to get the value of `$limit`

```
Error: check_disk.sh: line: 119 * 100 / : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ ")
```

Comment: is limit exported?

Comment: First, try to sanitize the input/variables. Make sure they are all numeric before doing arithmetic operation on them. Also the `$` for variable/parameter expansion is not required/needed in arithmetic operation, at least in `bash`. My guess is there are invisible characters rom the variables or empty variable., according to the error message.

Comment: `diskusb=10; limit=; disusdpercent=$(( diskusb * 100 / $limit))` Will show the same error. because the `$limit` variable is empty.

Comment: You need to show us more of the script before that error line, especially how and where you assign to limit.

Comment: From the error message, I conclude that `limit` is empty. Before asking such a question, always do some debugging by yourself, by setting `set -x`. At least this would show the content of the variables. I find it much more unusual that the line number in the error message is denoted as `??`. Are you inside an `eval` here?

Comment: Notes on this: (1) Don’t use `$` inside an arithmetic expression. There’s no reason for that and it can save some hassle with unset (empty) variables. (2) Use `set -u` to make debugging (even) easier. (3) Don’t use uppercase variable names. They are reserved (by convention) for environment variables, which you don’t want to change by accident.

Comment: How to provide command line option for limit